# CommandError: Unable to serialize database: 'utf-8' after command makemigrations

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I use Windows 11 Pro and Visual Studio Code.
I created a new almost empty database in pgadmin 4 (PostgreSQL 16).
I set the default settings in the project settings in django (settings.py):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5433',
    },
}
```

After the `python manage.py makemigrations` command I get the following error in the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\twitchtest\Myproject\project\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\twitchtest\Myproject\project\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\twitchtest\Myproject\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\twitchtest\Myproject\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\twitchtest\Myproject\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\twitchtest\Myproject\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\twitchtest\Myproject\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 106, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\twitchtest\Myproject\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 156, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "C:\Users\twitchtest\Myproject\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 313, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\twitchtest\Myproject\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 81, in applied_migrations   
    if self.has_table():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\twitchtest\Myproject\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 57, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\twitchtest\Myproject\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\twitchtest\Myproject\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 330, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\twitchtest\Myproject\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 306, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\twitchtest\Myproject\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\twitchtest\Myproject\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection    
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\twitchtest\Myproject\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\twitchtest\Myproject\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 270, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\twitchtest\Myproject\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\twitchtest\Myproject\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\twitchtest\Myproject\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 61: invalid continuation byte
```

I checked the computer name, it is in English.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it is the computer name that is the problem. Is the database using utf-8 encoding?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your comment, I figured out what was going on. It turns out there was a mismatch between the specified username and password in settings.py and the same values ​​in pgadmin that caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

The error was a discrepancy between the values ​​of "USER" and "PASSWORD" in settings.py and the same values ​​in pgadmin.